# how to make "button.des" from "button.png"?

Tags: graphics, sprite, sprite-sheet

Can someone describe me of Atlas(sprite sheet) making process that is the process of making **".des"** files from **".png"** files ?

Comment: What is a ".des" file? What do you have that loads that? Scratch that; it's Corel Designer. New question: what do either of these formats have to do with *OpenGL*?

Comment: A DES file is very tiny plain text file. In this file you can find information about the atlas file including: where to find atlas (resource) image AND describe the position of original image on atlas image.

Basically, this DES file tells us where certain images are in the big ATLAS image. As example if you have a folder called MainMenu and two files button.png and levelIcon.png after atlas making process you’ll have two DES files button.des and levelIcon.des and two big images MainMenu.png and MainMenu_hi.png ( *_hi.png is for Retina Displays and IPad )